# store path in variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In one of my helpers I have to differ if the user is on a profile or not. The helper returns an array full of URLs.

```
def get_options(profile)
  if profile
    url_arr = profile_infinite_path(user, ...)

    # .
    # .
    # do stuff with profile_infinite_path
  else
    url_arr = infinite_path(user, ...)

    # .
    # .
    # do same stuff with infinite_path
  end
end
```

I want to make this code more DRY, so my plan was to store the path as a variable and then simply calling all the remaining code only once.

```
def get_options(profile)
  if profile
    var_path = profile_infinite_path
  else
    var_path = infinite_path
  end

  url_arr = var_path(user, ...)

  # .
  # .
  # do stuff with var_path
end
```

I also tried storing the path as a method, but no luck there.

```
var_path = profile_infinite_path.method
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here. Since path helpers are methods, and methods can be invoked without arguments  simply by stating them, an assignment like `path = profile_inifite_path` gives the result of the method invocation.

You can defer invocation by using a symbol to refer to the method, and then sending it as a message when needed:

```
var_path = :profile_infinite_path
# ...
send(var_path, user, ...)
```

The symbol is the first argument to `send`, and it is followed by any arguments you would have given to the method.

The other way you could handle this is to wrap the method call in a proc and invoke it when needed:

```
var_path = ->(*args){ profile_infinite_path(*args) }
# ...
var_path.call(user, ...)
```

I tend to prefer `send` for situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Store only a symbol in your variable eg

```
var_path = :profile_infinite_path
```

Then you can do send(var_path, other_args) to get the real URL.
Eg if you have users:

```
var_path = :user_path
```

`send(var_path, 2)` would return `"/users/2"`

Comment: Thanks, a little styling would improve your answer ;) I'll upvote after you formatted it a bit.

Comment: There you go :-) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you can assign the results of an if-else expression to a variable. This allows you to call the desired method and assign the results like so:

```
url_arr = if profile
  profile_infinite_path(user, ...)
else
  infinite_path(user, ...)
end

# .
# .
# do stuff with url_arr
```